# New to React and cannot get ReactDOM to render javascript component

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-dom

I am learning react from Udemy (React - The Complete Guide (including Hooks, React Router, Redux) by Maximilian Schwarzmüller. On the course content 4.Writing our first react code, Max uses codepen.io to import the react and reactdom cdn links and babel preprocessor. I am not using codepen.io. I am importing the react and reactdom and babel preprocessor via the script tag before my  element tag. However, I get an Uncaught Syntax and Uncaught Reference error. My code is per below:-

HTML Code below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
      </head>
    <body>

       <div id="p1"></div>


       <div class="person">
       <h1>Akshar</h1>
       <p>Your Age: 27</p>
       </div>

       <script src="./app.js"></script>
       <script 
       src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/cjs/react.development.js"> 
       </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/cjs/react-dom- 
      server.browser.development.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel- 
      standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

CSS code below:-

```
      .person {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ccc;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 20px;
      }
```

app.js code below:-

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    function Person() {
    return (
    <div class="person">
    <h1>Max</h1>
    <p>Your Age: 28</p>
    </div>
     );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Person/>, document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

Comment: @nNeedOfKnowledge what is error?

Comment: Code works fine for me.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal I removed # from querySelector and I still get the same errors. I am using atom editor. Not sure if that piece of information is even relevant in this scenario but I thought to share it anyways.

Comment: @Andrew The error I am getting is:- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
react.development.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react.development.js:14
(anonymous) @ react.development.js:14
react-dom-server.browser.development.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react-dom-server.browser.development.js:14

Comment: Editor should not be an issue. Seems like you have some setup issue with React otherwise your code looks fine. https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-sis86

Comment: @MilindAgrawal Thanks for your comment. I think it might be a setup issue also. But i rather try to find out why its an issue before i continue going further along with the react course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here:

- The order of your scripts matter. The browser stops to load and process your scripts in the order it founds them. `<script src="./app.js"></script>` should be at the end.
  https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/loading-javascript/
- When you use React and ReactDOM from CDN they are added to the global scope (window in browsers). You don't use `import React from 'react';` and `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`. You just need to access the variables directly.
  https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

[Check this link too.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-use-cdn-link-in-react/244766)

Comment: Hi Johnny, thanks for your answer. I placed the <script src="./app.js"></script> at the end and removed import React from 'react' and import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'However, I still get the errors below:- react.development.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react.development.js:14
(anonymous) @ react.development.js:14
react-dom-server.browser.development.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react-dom-server.browser.development.js:14
(anonymous) @ react-dom-server.browser.development.js:14
app.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: I see you are using a `dom-server...` script. Use these:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>`
  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
`

Comment: Thanks Johnny. This removed the first two errors. I am now only left with a Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token <     (app.js:5). it seems that it has a problem with below code:-                        
         function Person() {
         return (
         <div class="person">  <---(has a problem with "<" syntax here)
        <h1>Max</h1>
        <p>Your Age: 28</p>
        </div>
          );
        }

Comment: This is because browsers don't understand JSX (you normally don't put html tags in js files) so, to tell the browser not to process your app.js file add `type="text/babel"` to it. As so: `<script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>` This way the browser is not going to touch that file but babel will transpile it to something the browser can understand.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. This worked and removed all the errors.

Comment: Hey man, even though i get no errors, i don't think the react is rendering the div in my browser. For instance, I should be seeing two div tags with two different names ("Akshar" & "Max") and age ("27" & "28"). I only see the one that is hardcoded   <div class="person">
      <h1>Akshar</h1>
      <p>Your Age: 27</p>
    </div>
<!-- and not the <div id="p1"></div>

Comment: Hey @InNeedOfKnowledge glad I can help. I did a Codepen with the setup that you have. It is pretty much the same that you have and it works for me. [Check it out.](https://codepen.io/jzabala/project/editor/ZegPyp)